# I get a class not found exception when i rename the package from "default package"

Tags: java, package, classnotfoundexception, default-package

I get a class not found exception when i rename the package from "default package" in java. When i run the code within the default package, the code works fine but when i paste the code into a new java project in eclipse and into a new package, there is a classnotfound exception thrown even when the class referred to above is clearly present in the new package. What is wrong? please help me :(

Comment: by the way the classes in the new package are compiled fine

Comment: -1 Because of absolute lack of even basic detail/information. I will +1 if this question is cleaned up (for future searching/viewing). See the comment by Mr. Skeet in his reply.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're still trying to *start* the application with the existing application launcher, which is referring to the class in the "default" package.

Either create a new launcher, or edit the details of the existing one.

Of course, that's assuming you get the exception on launch. If that's not the case, you need to give us a lot more details.

EDIT: Okay, now you've posted the exception, it makes a lot more sense - you're trying to deserialize data which includes a reference to the class `FaceBundle`. Renaming classes breaks serialized data - it's as simple as that.

You *can* fiddle around with things in Java serialization, but I haven't done so myself. I *suspect* you'd want to create your own subclass of `ObjectInputStream` and override `resolveClass`.

Comment: But still the classes before the one referred in the classnotfound exception are getting compiled without issues. Like the main class and a couple after that. The exception is thrown on the third class in the tree

Comment: here is the error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FaceBundle
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: ..contd
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)

Comment: ..contd: 
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at jrec2.EigenFaceCreator.readBundle(EigenFaceCreator.java:197)
 at jrec2.EigenFaceCreator.submitSet(EigenFaceCreator.java:151)
 at jrec2.EigenFaceCreator.readFaceBundles(EigenFaceCreator.java:112)
 at jrec2.TestFaceRecognition.main(TestFaceRecognition.java:25)

Comment: No the launcher ain't the problem

Comment: @DEKE Consider updating the original post with the details (Just the first ~6 lines of the exception) and removing these comments. Also explain when the exception occurs. (Also, note that `FaceBundle` is non-qualified here.)

Comment: @DEKE: It makes a lot more sense now you've included the stack trace. I don't know why you didn't say it was while you were trying to read data in the first place - we'd have got to the answer quicker.